# E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

Hi am working on a PHP site , it is an old system and i got an error

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead...

For now i am not going to change my queries to `mysqli` or `PDO` , i simply tried to add

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

to my php.ini  and to remove the deprecated error messages . my php.ini is in C:/xampp/php/php.ini  , after i added the value i restarted apache . also i tried with

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED
```

also i tried with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

in my PHP , common header function , but the messages are showing . i want to remove them .

my MySQL version is 5.6.21

PHP version is 5.6.3

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 5):

Nothing present in your logs?

A quick browse around the net & SO seems to warrant trying this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Which should show all errors except for the deprecated warnings.

Your other option would be to specify only what you want to be displayed in your `php.ini` file.

```
error_reporting = |E_ERROR|E_WARNING|.....etc
```

---

References

- [`error_reporting();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
- [`Predefined constants (flags)`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

And if the above doesn't work, [this answer on ServerFault might clear things up (Providing different options for you to try.)](https://serverfault.com/a/265858)

Comment: E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED doesn't make sense. E_ALL includes everything ORing it with anything else should still produce the behavior of E_ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you see other error level message. Try:

> error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);